# Node.js Express custom process.env variables not accessible from all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, .env

I am working on an app with Node.js and express and am using the 'dotenv' package to config/load my variables from the .env file. My issue is that I can only access the variables I defined in the main index.js file and not in all of the project files. I would like to be able to do so to do stuff like set up the db config in a separate file.

database=application`

And this is what I have in `index.js`:
`const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })
const HOSTNAME = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;`

As I said, I have no issue accessing these variables in the `index.js` file but if I try to access `process.env.DB_SERVER` for example from a different file, the value is undefined.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Are you configure dotenv before trying to read env variables in your other files?

Answer (score 1):

Note that all imports modules in your `index.js` file are evaluated before index.js is being evaluated.

This means that `dotenv.config({ path: 'config/config.env' });` is being executed only after other imported were executed, so inside those modules the DB_SERVER environment variable is not yet loaded.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me solve it. I just had to make sure I was executing `.config()` before I imported the other modules. I really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Just keep

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'; or const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

At the top of your server.ts/js or index.ts/js file and it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

The `dotenv.config()` should come before importing the routes in the index.js